# Oracle SQL regular expression replacement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Employees table where I have columns such as `last_name` `first_name`,`salary`, etc.. I want to write a query which will replace

- S or s to 'K'
- K or k to 'A'
- A or a to 'E'
- E or e to 'S'

for each `last_name` in the Employees table. Basically there are two ways to do it

1. translate: if I use this I am missing out either on lower case or upper case matching,e.g. `translate(last_name,[skae],[kaes])`
2. regexp_replace: I tried this, but from second replacement it is replacing the character with null. `regexp_replace(last_name,'[(s|S)(k|K)(a|A)(e|E)]',[KAES],1,0,'i']`

Comment: As Gordon Linoff showed in his answer, TRANSLATE makes several single-character, one-to-one translations or substitutions in one operation, but you have to deal with uppercase and lowercase characters individually. REPLACE and REGEXP_REPLACE search for occurrences of the *entire* search_string and substitute the *entire* replacement_string. There is only one "substitution", though it may have multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`translate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) for single character replacement:

```
select translate(last_name, 'SsKkAaEs', 'KKAAEESS')
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but I think you meant to write select translate(last_name, 'SsKkAaEe', 'KKAAEESS')

Comment: Abhishek, if the solution worked then please mark the answer as correct. It helps others afterwards.